# Looping through series in VBA and coloring according to cell criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a vba code that will loop through all the series in chart and color that series depending on a values in a table on that sheet. This is one of my first VBA codes so I am very novice. I have the looping part done:

```
Dim cht As Chart
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart

    'loop through series in chart to format lines

    Dim ser As Series
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rcode As Integer
    Dim gcode As Integer
    Dim bcode As Integer
    
  
    i = 1
    For Each ser In cht.SeriesCollection
    MsgBox "color" & i
    
    rcode = 255
    gcode = 255
    bcode = 150
    

    Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = RGB(rcode, gcode, bcode)
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
        i = i + 1
    Next ser
```

Now, I am trying to add the part where it changes the color for each series. I have tried writing this several ways, but keep getting object mismatch errors. In the sheet that this chart is on, the series names are in column K, to their right is the identifier that I want to color code based on. For example, series 15 is named "15" and next to the 15 in column K is an A. This A indicates that I want it to be plotted in blue. I understand that once I assign a variable to this identifier, a simple if statement will get me to the correct color.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I added that part of the code, also I change from color index to rgb, but I need to vlookup the rgb code for each series on another tab in excel.

Comment: Try `With ser.Format.Line` instead of `Format.Line`